# Joomla! Megamenu image

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, megamenu

Good morning at all.

I have a problem with a Joomla! Megamenu.

This is the link of my website: http://lorenzovinci.ilgiornale.it

If you click on "Rubriche" section, you can see the problem. Images that we had insert into Megamenu you see all, but I set that the image show only when you hover on a section of this menu.

I think it's a problem of jQuery , and yet in the backend I set the megamenu should not use the js and manually set the display of the submenu only to click.

This is the code:

```
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                         jQuery("body").on("click","span.haschild",function(){

            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('opened_submenu')) {
              jQuery(this).next('.childcontent').fadeOut();
              jQuery(this).removeClass('opened_submenu');
              jQuery(this).css("color","#878786");
            }
            else {
              jQuery(this).next('.childcontent').fadeIn();
              jQuery(this).addClass('opened_submenu');
              jQuery(this).css("color","#e06f19");
            }

            jQuery("span.haschild").not(this).each(function(){


              jQuery(this).next('.childcontent').fadeOut();
              jQuery(this).removeClass('opened_submenu');

                console.log("click");
         });                    
    });
```

There is anyone who can help me?